# Can I allow root to su any other user?

Tags: linux, centos

I have this centos VPS with 5 accounts; then I enabled one user to ssh, disabled root login, and have shell disabled for every other user account..

Is to possible to permit root to su the other ones while ssh direct access for those users is disabled?

Comment: You cannot _prevent_ `root` from `su`ing to _any_ user.

Comment: Also note that Server Fault is [explicitly for business environments](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). This question isn't; I've flagged it for migration to [Unix and Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @BlacklightShining you can, if you use PAM. In Ubuntu's default `/etc/pam.d/su` is the comment: `You can also add "group=foo"
to the end of this line if you want to use a group other
than the default "root" (but this may have side effect of
denying "root" user, unless she's a member of "foo" or explicitly
permitted earlier by e.g. "sufficient pam_rootok.so").`. So removing the `rootok` line earlier and using a group of which root isn't member might prevent root from `su`ing to another user until root learns to use `sudo` or `usermod` or any of the editors available.

Comment: @muru I stand corrected. In any case, `root` can call `setuid()` and then `exec()`, to the same effect.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, provided that you disabled root's ssh access and not root itself.

However, for accounts with disabled shells you'll have to tell `su` what shell to use.

`su -s /bin/bash -l $user`